# How the reverse operation for multiplying polynomial is called?

Tags: polynomials

Say I have a polynomial and I want to know which components it consists of.

> As an example,
>   $$yx^2 + y^2 = 2y + 63 - 7x^2 \iff yx^2 + 7x^2 + y^2 - 2y - 63 = 0\\
> \iff (y+7)(y+x^2-9) = 0 \iff \begin{cases} y = -7,\\y = 9 - x^2\end{cases}$$

There are some techniques for some easy equations, but is there a general algorithm for solving such things?

Comment: You want to find its roots, which is precisely what the example is doing.

Comment: Ok thanks. But how can one find them in the example?

Comment: It's generally not a trivial process, and varies from polynomial to polynomial. Sometimes you can just notice the roots, sometimes you have to substitute values into the polynomial and see which ones give you zero, other types of polynomials have more generalised methods. What you've asked is actually a huge part of algebra _because_ of how non-trivial it is.

Comment: [This is one example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260918/factor-a-polynomial), and [so is this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260722/prove-that-f-x4-4x216-in-mathbbq-is-irreducible/1260803#1260803).

Comment: Consider searching for _polynomial factorisation_ and you may find techniques that help you.

Comment: Thank you Bill Wallis! :)