# Show that a polynomial is irreducible on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I would like to show that $P(X)=X^4-20X^2+16$ is irreducible on $\mathbb{Q}$, how to proceed ?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260722/prove-that-f-x4-4x216-in-mathbbq-is-irreducible). The proof is similar.

Comment: $\Delta=10^2-16=84≠n^2, n\in\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 1):

By the rational root theorem, $P$ has no rational root. So we only need to study a possible factorization with integer coefficients
$$
P(x)=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)
$$
Comparison with the coefficients gives equations over the integers with no solution.

Comment: This is a quadratic equation respect to $X^2$ isn't it? So, is it enough to show that $X^2 $ (after solving quadratic) is irrational? Because, If $X^2$ is irrational, then $X$ irrational. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: You mean like egreg's answer in the duplicate?